# Some values showing as disabled in tableview when they shouldn't

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

Creating a simple currency exchange app where users can select one currency from list, and then another from the same list which is called, and then redirect to a new view where the currencies are compared. After the first selection, I disable the selection option so that it cannot be selected again. Although it correctly disables the value I want, it also randomly disables another x amount which I can't figure why. Not sure what I have coded wrong so any help appreciated. The function that does the disabling is in the `cellForRowAt`

```
 class SelectCurrencyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var selectedCurrency: String?
    var codesToConvert = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // Get the JSON data to insert into the table
    func parseJSONData()-> Array<Any> {
        var finalArray = [Any]()
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "currencies", withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                if var jsonArray = jsonResult as? [String] {

                    while jsonArray.count > 0 {
                        let result: [String] = Array(jsonArray.prefix(2))
                        finalArray.append(result)
                        jsonArray.removeFirst(2)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return finalArray
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return parseJSONData().count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellController
        if let array = parseJSONData()[indexPath.row] as? [String]{

            cell.countryCodeLabel.text = array[0]
            cell.currencyLabel.text = array[1]
            cell.countryFlag.image = UIImage(named: array[0])

            // if selected is the same as the current one, disable that row
            if (selectedCurrency == array[0]){
                cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                cell.countryCodeLabel.alpha = 0.3
                cell.currencyLabel.alpha = 0.3
                cell.countryFlag.alpha = 0.3
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (selectedCurrency != nil){
            if let array = parseJSONData()[indexPath.row] as? [String] {
                codesToConvert.append(selectedCurrency!)
                codesToConvert.append(array[0])
            }
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "viewConversions", sender: self)

        } else {
            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tableView") as! SelectCurrencyTableViewController
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

            if let array = parseJSONData()[indexPath.row] as? [String]{
                vc.selectedCurrency = array[0]
                show(vc, sender: self)
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60.0
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "viewConversions" {
            let VCTV = segue.destination as! ViewConversionsTableViewController
            VCTV.codesToConvert = codesToConvert
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (selectedCurrency == array[0]){
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    cell.countryCodeLabel.alpha = 0.3
    cell.currencyLabel.alpha = 0.3
    cell.countryFlag.alpha = 0.3
} else {
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.countryCodeLabel.alpha = 1
    cell.currencyLabel.alpha = 1
    cell.countryFlag.alpha = 1
}
```

Comment: This worked thanks! I will accept as answer in a few mins when it lets me. I'm not sure why it was failing before and why the reverse is necessary

Answer (score 2):

Note that table view cells are *reused*, so when you dequeue a cell in `didSelectRowAt`, the cell you get might be one of the old cells in the table view. Table views work like this so that there aren't a lot of `UITableViewCell` objects being created if your table view is really long.

If you just so happens to dequeue one of the old cells which is disabled, that cell will stay disabled, which is what caused the unexpected behaviour. To fix this, you just need to set the cell to the enabled state when it should be enabled:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellController
    if let array = parseJSONData()[indexPath.row] as? [String]{

        cell.countryCodeLabel.text = array[0]
        cell.currencyLabel.text = array[1]
        cell.countryFlag.image = UIImage(named: array[0])

        // if selected is the same as the current one, disable that row
        if (selectedCurrency == array[0]){
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            cell.countryCodeLabel.alpha = 0.3
            cell.currencyLabel.alpha = 0.3
            cell.countryFlag.alpha = 0.3
        } else {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.countryCodeLabel.alpha = 1
            cell.currencyLabel.alpha = 1
            cell.countryFlag.alpha = 1
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

I also recommend you not to call `parseJSONData` in the table view data source methods. You can just call it once in `viewDidLoad`, store it in a property, and read that property instead. You don't need to re-parse the JSON data every time you need a new cell.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!